# my app does not run on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an app that runs on **tablet devices** and **emulator Android 3.2 API Level 13** successfully but it does not run on **emulator Android 4.2 API Level 17**

Why does this happen and this emulator is not shown in compatible devices?

I should mention that I am using `Fragment` and `ViewPager` in my application.

The build target of my project is Android 4.2 API Level 17

**Update:**

The problem solved. I deleted and created the emulator again!!! :-?

Answer (score 0):

run `adb logcat` right before launching the app and you will get at least a clue ...

Comment: that emulator is not shown in compatible devices. So I can not choose it and run my app

Comment: @breceivemail so the problem it's what ? the app or the emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your AndroidManifest: uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion=YourAPILevelTarget